# Can I include cppcheck suppression within a function header?

Tags: c++, c, header, doxygen, cppcheck

I have added an inline comment to suppress a cppcheck unusedFunction warning for a function, but I would like to include this within the function header so that Doxygen can document all of the unused functions (I am implementing an API, so I have many functions that will not be used in my source).  I would prefer not to suppress all unusedFunction errors, but rather on a per-function basis.

I would like to do something like this:

```
/**
 * API function description
 * 
 * @param p1 function pointer to the ...
 * @return 0 if successful, -1 otherwise.
 * // cppcheck-suppress unusedFunction
 */
int CreateTask(Task_FuncPtr p1)
{    
    return doSomething();
}
```

But when I do this, cppcheck does not "see" the inline suppression.  If I move it outside the header, but just before the function declaration then the suppression works.  The [cppcheck documentation](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf) seems to imply that the suppression needs to be directly before the line generating then error.

Has any had success with this?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at `cppcheck` sources (file [`preprocessor.cpp`](http://trac.cppcheck.net/browser/lib/preprocessor.cpp) function `RemoveComments()`), it seems that you cannot do it.

The code to identify comments is:

```
if (str.compare(i, 2, "//") == 0) { /* ... */ }
```

and

```
else if (str.compare(i, 2, "/*") == 0) { /* ... */ }
```

When a comment is found, the code that manages warning suppression is:

```
if (_settings && _settings->_inlineSuppressions) {
    std::istringstream iss(comment);
    std::string word;
    iss >> word;
    if (word == "cppcheck-suppress") {
        iss >> word;
        if (iss)
            suppressionIDs.push_back(word);
    }
}
```

So `cppcheck` will skip spaces and check the first token immediately after `//` or `/*`.

Unfortunately Doxygen's special comment blocks start with `/**`, `///`, `/*!` or `//!` and the third character prevents the "correct match".

Changing:

```
if (word == "cppcheck-suppress") { /* ... */ }
```

into:

```
if (contains(word, "cppcheck-suppress")) { /* ... */ }
// or if (ends_with(word, "cppcheck-suppress"))
```

should allow what you want:

```
/**
 * API function description
 *
 * @param p1 function pointer to the ...
 * @return 0 if successful, -1 otherwise.
 */
/** cppcheck-suppress unusedFunction */
```

or

```
/// API function description
///
/// @param p1 function pointer to the ...
/// @return 0 if successful, -1 otherwise.
///
/// cppcheck-suppress unusedFunction
```

You can probably open a ticket on http://trac.cppcheck.net/